# Proving that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos{y}}{y^{2}(|\log{\lambda}-\log{y}|+1)}dy<\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

During a proof in the book I'm reading, there is an integral that is not clear to me is finite; It's the next:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos{y}}{y^{2}(|\log{\lambda}-\log{y}|+1)}dy$$ where $\lambda>0.$

I've tried to find a function which dominates the integrand with infinite integral but I don't get it.
Why this integral is finite?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{1-\cos y}{y^{2}}\right|<1,~~~~y\in(0,\epsilon_{0}]
\end{align*}
for a small $\epsilon_{0}>0$.

For small enough $0<y<\min\{\epsilon_{0},\lambda\}$, one has $\lambda/y>1$, so $|\log\lambda-\log y|+1=\log(\lambda/y)+1>1$, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{|\log\lambda-\log y|+1}<1,
\end{align*}
so we have controlled that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\min\{\epsilon_{0},\lambda\}}\dfrac{|1-\cos y|}{y^{2}(|\log\lambda-\log y|+1)}dy<\infty.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|1-\cos y|}{y^{2}(|\log\lambda-\log y|+1)}dy\leq 2\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y^{2}}dy<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for answer. I only have a doubt: How do you ensure the first inequality in your post?

Comment: A cheating way is to do $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}$ to that by using L'Hopital.

Comment: You're right! Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(y)}{y^2(|\log\lambda-\log y|+1)}dy<\int_{1}^\infty\frac{1}{y^2}dy+\int_{0}^1\frac{1-\cos(y)}{y^2(|\log\lambda-\log y|+1)}dy$$

Since $1-\cos(y)$ has a max of $2$ and $|\log\lambda-\log y|$ is always positive. The second integral on the right is taken over a finite subset of the real numbers and at $y=0$ it can be shown that the limit exists using L'Hopitals Rule.

Comment: You need  more on why the second integral on the right is finite.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've voted for the other answer for the details. I appreciate your help.